# How to use variable as a path for find command

Tags: string, variables, path, find

Can someone give me a hint, how I can make the following bash script run properly:

```
path="/path/"
excludepath="! -path \"/path/to/exclude/*\" "

find "$path" "$excludepath" -name *."txt" -type f
```

When I try to run it I get:

```
find: `! -path "/path/to/exclude/*"': No such file or directory
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Root path is $path, /path/. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Derp, never mind, selective blindness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was the fact that `"$excludepath"` is a single argument, even if it contains spaces. To put several arguments, use an array of strings instead of a string:

```
excludepath=(! -path "*webshow*")
find "$path" "${excludepath[@]}" -name "*.txt" -type f
```

This is a bashism, though (people that stumble onto this and don't use `bash` will need to do something else).